# How to encrypt the visual selection?

Tags: encryption

For e.g. Vim allows `g?` to run ROT13 on a visual selection. What are the inbuilt (preferably strong like `blowfish2`) encryption methods available for encrypting only a part of file.

Comment: Vim doesn't include support for this; you'll need to use an external command such as `age`, `openssl`, `gpg`.

Comment: you may be able to make use of the filter function together with an external encryption program